Early to mid 2000s Mech anime/show?
This is a show from my childhood, and I remember very little of it, but one major thing stands out: the mech. So, the body was spherical while the head, arms, legs, and pelvis area where all boxy and rectangular.  The pilot would sit in the head, and the top opened like a hatch. The entire thing was a darker blue, and the sphere body would separate in the middle to reveal machine guns. It was around the time Gundam started to really hit it off in the US, and it even went as far as to get a toy line. If I remeber correctly, the show was grittier than Gundam. That's all I can remember, would really appreciate any help!

I have no first-hand knowledge but a cursory search appears that what you seek may be Gundam related due to the sheer amount of offshoots at the time, possibly the original "Mobile Suit Gundam" TV series itself.  Do any of these images look familiar?
http://amphibiousmobilesuits.tumblr.com/page/4
Specifically this? http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/MSM-03_Gogg
Background from Gundam wikipedia page:

The majority of Gundam animation, including the earliest series, occur in what is known as the Universal Century (UC) calendar era, with later series set in alternate calendars or timelines. Universal Century makes up the dominating majority of the entire franchise. While many new Gundam stories are told in their own parallel universe with independent timelines, giving them a greater degree of creative freedom, the original U.C. storyline continues to be extremely popular for a variety of reasons. It established the series and delivered many of its best moments, as well as setting the standard for realistic hard science fiction in anime; the original Gundam marked the maturing of the Giant Robot genre. Also, nostalgia for the oldest of the Gundam shows (and Gundam's resulting status as a pop-culture icon in Japan) is still a major factor in its continuing success.
  The creation of the separate timelines were originally stand-alone works that did not require prior knowledge of the Universal Century timeline to understand or appreciate the story's background. These timelines define Gundam differently and portray conflicts in entirely different settings and circumstances to other entries, including the definition of Gundam. For example, the original Gundam was considered a military general-purpose prototype mobile suit and a "Gundam" from G Gundam is considered a name for a mobile fighter whose purpose is to compete against other Gundams


Thank you for the reply, but it was not Gundam. Had a completely different animation style.

Could it be Megas XLR?  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0361201/
It ran 2004-2005 and there indeed were a lot of guns. In one episode, Megas is fighting against very spherical robot from the 50's.



